# MySQL: merge several large tables and add values, optimization

Tags: mysql, optimization, merge, union

I have several large tables with fields like:

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| fid1  | varchar(10) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| fid2  | varchar(10) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| cnt   | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

where I have index on `{fid1,fid2,cnt}`, and each table has more than `20000000` rows.

I want to merge these tables into one, in the way that if both `fid1` and `fid2` match, then the new `cnt` value would be the sum of `cnt` in these tables.

I tried the way suggested in [merge and add values from two tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647946/merge-and-add-values-from-two-tables), and get something like

```
SELECT COALESCE(A.fid1, B.fid1) AS fid1, COALESCE(A.fid2, B.fid2) AS fid2, (COALESCE(A.cnt,0)+COALESCE(B.cnt,0))
FROM test1 A LEFT JOIN test2 B ON a.fid1 = b.fid1 AND A.fid2 = B.fid2
UNION
SELECT COALESCE(A.fid1, B.fid1) AS fid1, COALESCE(A.fid2, B.fid2) AS fid2, (COALESCE(A.cnt,0)+COALESCE(B.cnt,0))
FROM test1 A RIGHT JOIN test2 B ON a.fid1 = b.fid1 AND A.fid2 = B.fid2
```

However, since I have several tables and they are all very large, this method with `UNION` is very time consuming. Is there any other way to efficiently implement it or any way to optimize this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be achieved in very efficient and simple way.

Step 1:

```
Alter table test1 
  add constraint fid1_fid2_unique UNIQUE (fid1,fid2);
```

Step 2:

```
insert into test1 
   select  test2.fid1,test2.fid2,test2.cnt  from test2
 on duplicate key update test1.cnt=test1.cnt+test2.cnt ;
```

Similarly multiple tables can be handled.

You may verify the result at below link:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/07c6b/1

Comment: thanks! so in this way, no other index would be needed right?

Comment: I believe this is slower than the union way, because 1: it keeps an index up to date with each insert 2: updates a result row more than once, and depending on the data redundancy, that could mean 7-20-200 times slower performance. Also note that unique indexes are especially not suggested as of mysql doc: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html The original question was about speed, and not the simplest or prettier one. :)

Comment: Also note, that this way, you'd loose the original data in test1.

Comment: This one also fails if the original test1 table has duplicates. Sorry for nitpicking, I left this window open from yesterday. :)

Comment: @PetrosHu : It was assumed that test1 has no duplicate or without data.
Your solution `UNION` removes duplicate records(inner query)..as a matter of fact `SUM` function gives wrong answer in your query.You should update it with `UNION ALL`. Sorry for nitpicking  :)

Answer (score 1):

One can't speed up a UNION on several tables, as UNION is simply a concatenation, and in your use case you must read all rows from all your tables. So if you've got 20 tables, and select from each individually, that would not be faster than one union (given the same filters)

If you'd like to combine several million rows, the time it takes depends on the select-s and on the writes too, and writing is always slower, so:

1. create table new_table.... and DON'T add keys, those just slow down the writes now
2. don't use any tricks that touch one record more than once, it's better to sum in memory, and write once
3. use INSERT INTO new_table SELECT ... as it's the fastest way to write huge amounts of data selected locally (it keeps everything in the servers memory, no network touched :) )
4. don't use LEFT and RIGHT join, use outer join
5. Use some script or code to generate the joins into one long query:

   ```
   INSERT INTO new_table
   SELECT fid1,fid2, sum(cnt) as cnt FROM
   (
   SELECT fid1, fid2, cnt FROM table1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT fid1, fid2, cnt FROM table2
   UNION ALL
   SELECT fid1, fid2, cnt FROM table3
   UNION ALL
   SELECT fid1, fid2, cnt FROM table4
   UNION ALL
   SELECT fid1, fid2, cnt FROM table5
   UNION ALL
   SELECT fid1, fid2, cnt FROM table6
   ) GROUP BY fid1, fid2;
   ```

   If you run out of buffers, you might consider not doing everything at once, but sum up table1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 into sum1, table 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20 into sum2, and at the end sum the sums.  This means more work, and more allocated storage space, and more disk io, but the peak buffer usage is lower.

   And at last: you can add (or enable) the keys you need.

   Hints:

   - in this special case, you're probably get faster results with myisam if you don't update the tables too frequently
   - if you work with large datasets your database servers memory is the key parameter in performance (and ssd is the second :) ), so you should spend time on tweaking the configuration of buffer sizes. It might take you 8 hours of tweaking, but you might win 40 hours of runtime, and also 40 hours each time you have to repeat this.
   - If you don't know what to set in your mysql.cnf at least take a look at Percona's configuration wizard, https://tools.percona.com/, that's a not bad start.

Update: Corrected UNION ALL as noted by user seahawk

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. I'm not sure what you mean by `DON'T add keys, those just slow down the writes now`. Wouldn't indexes be needed for the SUM and GROUP BY operation?

Comment: If you have a table with no keys, you can insert a million row nearly as fast as the disk can write.   Later, when you inserted every row, you can use "alter table add key". The other way around this is when you create the empty table with keys, and then "alter table new_table DISABLE KEYS", do the batch insert, and later "alter table new_table ENABLE KEYS", to let it rebuild the indexes. The concept is that building the index once is faster than keeping up with 200million inserts individually. Also while indexes are good when selecting on the insert side they don't help you...

Comment: I'd also point out, that if you're into doing these kind of processing every day, for years, you should probably look into some distributed processing systems like hadoop, as they are more suited for "huge datasets with not so versatile usage patterns". (So you can't just write up any kind of select or join in a minute, but if you've got tons of data and 20 servers, and you need them to run reliably, and you don't really need the RDBMS features, that's the way to go.)

Comment: I see, indeed inserting rows into table with keys is much slower. Thanks again for the detailed information!

Comment: This query gives wrong result. Please replace `union` by `UNION ALL`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a lot of details of your scenario - but i'm assuming this is non-production database, and db load doesn't matter (since you're doing massive unions anyway). Also assuming you want a MySQl solution.

Try this:

Insert all your data into 1 giant table. 
Add a composite index (fld1, fld2) on it. 
Then run a group by query 

`SELECT SUM(cnt), fld1, fld2 FROM table_name GROUP BY fld1,fld2;`

How long does the Union take? That'll be the worst case. And let us know how long your final solution takes.

Good luck!

Comment: Inserting all data into one giant table, then adding an index, and then later grouping by that is suboptimal. This would read all records, write all records, then the index building would read all records, write nearly the same amount, then the select group would read again, and then you still have to store the result. Thats 3 full reads ~3 full writes for the whole dataset. On the other hand the one big union would read all rows once, process them and write some of them out once. (and use up all memory and buffers on the way, but thats what servers are made for).